# HTML5 Multiple Images on the same line with figure captions

Tags: css, html

After thoroughly looking for an answer to my problem, I turn to you guys to try and help me out. Im trying to build my first full site which is on a theme park. I've been trying to get 3 icons on the same line, which i achieved in the first place, however as soon as i added figure captions with HTML5 the images stack on top of each other with the caption underneath. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="popular">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/kidsride.jpg" alt="popular-rides1" 
class="left">
        <figcaption> Rocket Run </figcaption>

        <img src="images/duelingdrags.jpg" alt="popular-rides2" 
class="center">
        <figcaption> Dueling Dragons </figcaption>

        <img src="images/familyfall.jpg" alt="popular-rides3" 
class="right">
        <figcaption> Family Fall </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popular{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.left{
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #000);
    float:left;
}

.center{
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #000);
}

.right{
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #000);
}

figure{
    display: table;
    width: auto;

}

figcaption{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-row;
    font-family: helvetica;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px
}
```